# How to make image fade on timer

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

I want to make a photo to disappear millimeter by millimeter while the timer passes.

For example I have countdown timer, and here is the code:

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime){
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock(){
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if(t.total<=0){
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
}

var deadline = 'April 24 2016 00:00:00 UTC+01:00';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 65px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: 0F0F13;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #0F0F13;
 display: inline-block;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">hr</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">min</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">sec</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to add a picture which will disappear slowly while the time is passing...

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you wanting another image to appear after the one has disappeared?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: you could put the image in a div with overflow hidden and then set the height to a percentage of the image based on the timer

Comment: Yes that would be cool, when the timer passes and the image dissapear would be great to appear another picture.

Comment: @Pete how do i do that?

Comment: hire a web developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create an `img`, and put it inside a container. The container will have `overflow: hidden`. Then convert your total time to seconds.
Once you have that, do `imagewidth/seconds`. This will give you an answer that will be used to determine how many pixels per second sthe image will move. E.g. An image that is `100px` wide, to disapear over a period of `50` seconds, `100/50 = 2 pixels per second`.

Then a simple timer, `setInterval()`, to run once a second. It adds `2px` to the `margin-left` property every second. The image will have completely disappeared just as the timer gets to `0`.

For example:

- Time for image to disappear - `10 seconds`
- Width of image - `100px`

`100/10 = 10 pixels per second`

- 10th second - `margin-left += 10px` = `0px += 10px` = `10px`
- 9th second - `margin-left += 10px` = `10px += 10px` = `20px`
- 8th second - `margin-left += 10px` = `20px += 10px` = `30px`
- 7th second - `margin-left += 10px` = `30px += 10px` = `40px`
- 6th second - `margin-left += 10px` = `40px += 10px` = `50px`
- 5th second - `margin-left += 10px` = `50px += 10px` = `60px`
- 4th second - `margin-left += 10px` = `60px += 10px` = `70px`
- 3rd second - `margin-left += 10px` = `70px += 10px` = `80px`
- 2nd second - `margin-left += 10px` = `80px += 10px` = `90px`
- Last second - `margin-left += 10px` = `90px += 10px` = `100px` - **The image has disappeared completely**